# Can't generate data from object list Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I'm a newbie.

I'm coding function showing related article.

Backend code using Java with REST api. When i call API using axios.

But the view is not show data.

I checked API and it returned data.

This is my HTML code:

```
    <div class='related-article-list'>
        <div id="list-related-el">
            <related-list></related-list>
        </div>

    <template id="related-list">
        <div class="ralated-article-container" v-for="r in relatedLists" :key="r.id">
            <div class="ralated-article-title">
                <a v-bind:href="r.link">{{r.title}}</a>
            </div>
            <div class="user-name">
                <a v-bind:href="r.userLink">{{r.user}}</a>
            </div>
            <div class="view-total">
                <p>{{r.view}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
</div>
```

This is my Script code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var id = ([[${ topicChapter.getId() }]]);
                var listRelated = new Vue({
                    el: "#list-related-el",
                    components: {
                        'related-list': {
                            template: '#related-list',
                            data() {
                                return {
                                    url: "api/get-related-article",
                                    id: id,
                                    relatedLists: [],
                                    dataSize: 0
                                };
                            },
    
                            methods: {
                                getData: function () {
                                    axios.get(`${this.url}id=${this.id}`).then(response => {
                                             this.relatedLists = response.data.data;
                                    });
                                }
    
                            },
                            watch: {
                                page: {
                                    immediate: true,
                                    handler(newVal, oldVal) {
                                        this.getData();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    
            })
        </script>
```

Comment: Firstly, you seem to be mixing jQuery with Vue.  `$(document).ready(function () {` is jQuery syntax. This is a bad practice (unnecessary too, as Vue does what jQuery does and arguably more) that will lead to unexpected results. You will also add unnecessary bloat to your project.

Secondly, what is this `page` you are watching? Is it a prop? A bit of state? or a property of the data property? I can't seem to locate it. Are you sure `this.getData` is getting called? If page(which I can't locate) doesn't change, `this.getData` doesn't get called.

Comment: Check VueDevTools and see if the component `related-list` contains a variable named `relatedLists`. If not - you should send it through a prop.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried placing this.getData() in a mounted hook?

```
mounted()  {
this.getData();
}
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted